# Posts are not found when using a custom nav menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpres Bootstrap theme/framework. In the header.php page I've created a script that build the nav menu and automatically adds the dropdown sub-menus (with sub-links) when it needs. The script works well, but the problem is that when I view a post (in my case it's a page) I get "Not Found". Instead if I disable the script and use the default menu the posts (pages) are correctly showed. I think there is something wrong in my script. I paste it here and hope someone could solve this mystery.

```
<?php

    $menu_name = 'main_nav';

    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

        // --- Menu ---
        echo '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '" class="nav">';


        foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
            $title = $menu_item->title;
            $url = $menu_item->url;




            $args_post = array(
                'category_name' => $title,
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );  
            query_posts($args_post); 


            if (have_posts()){
?>
                <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $title; ?><b class="caret"></b></a>


                <!-- Sub-menu -->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu submenu">
                <?php
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  
                ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                ?>
                </ul> <!-- end Sub-menu -->




<?php
            wp_reset_query();

            } else {
                echo '<li class="">';
                echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a>';               
            } 




            echo '</li>'; 
        } // foreach
        echo '</ul>'; 

    } else {
        echo '<ul><li>Menu "' . $menu_name . '" not defined.</li></ul>';
    }



?>
```

Comment: Have you read all the caveats listed toward the beginning of the documentation for `query_posts()`?

Comment: I've seen them but I don't get what's wrong

Comment: I've called the wp_reset_query() but nothing